# C# - Silverlight - How to i bind the width of an element to an other element such that its OneWay Binding?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, binding, width

i have two TextBoxes with `x:Name="TextBoxName"` and `x:Name="TextBoxPhone"` i want to be able to bind the width of `TextBoxName` to `TextBoxPhone` such that if `TextBoxPhone` Width changes i want the width of `TextBoxName` to change too how do i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In Silverlight 3:**

For the `TextBox` called `TextBoxName` set `Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=TextBoxPhone}"`

Good example here http://www.silverlightshow.net/tips/XAML-Element-Binding.aspx

**In Silverlight 2:**

You would need to do some more work. Example here: http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/02/elementname-binding-in-silverlight-via-attached-behaviours/

Comment: Alex, can You bring some light, why this can not work if I bind Element Property to custom DependencyProperty? I've binded to ColumnDefinition.ActualWidth. On OrientationChange ActualWidth changed, but not propagated to binded property.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="190,81,0,0" Name="TextBoxName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding ElementName=TextBoxPhone, Path=Width, Mode=OneWay}" />
<TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="194,192,0,0" Name="TextBoxPhone" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`<TextBox Name="TextBoxName" Width="{Binding ElementName=TextBoxPhone, Path=Width, Mode=OneWay}" />`